# How to get keys and values of arrays inside Multidimensional array in javascript

Tags: javascript, multidimensional-array, rxjs

I Have a multidimensional array such as

```
MultArrary = [
['a','b'],
['c','d'],
['f','g']
]
```

What i need is to get the key and value of each array inside the array and push it into another array

```
Expected array1 = ['a','c','f'];
expected array2 = ['b','d','g'];
```

Any ideas how to achieve this with javascript or rxjs will be great

Comment: You aren't getting the keys anywhere. You're just grabbing the values at a particular index.

Comment: These aren't really "keys" and "values", they are all values. One happens to be index zero, the other at index one. You should know how to do that, if you can handle arrays.

Comment: So, we've seen the requirements you have, but I haven't seen any code you tried. Looks like you'll need a couple of `map` calls, or possibly a `reduce`. Maybe you can look those functions up and see what you can do.

Answer (score 2):

Easiest thing to do (while not syntatically correct, see the comments below your question) in your case is to use a [**Map**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map) (provided you are within an ecmascript6 capable environment):

```js
    var MultiArray = [
      ['a', 'b'],
      ['c', 'd'],
      ['f', 'g']
    ];

    var m = new Map(MultiArray);

    var index0 = Array.from(m.keys());
    var index1 = Array.from(m.values());

    console.log(index0, index1);
```

Comment: Beautiful use of `Map` and `Array.from`.

Answer (score 1):

Using Underscore.js you can do it with [unzip](http://underscorejs.org/#unzip):

```js
var MultArrary = [
  ['a', 'b'],
  ['c', 'd'],
  ['f', 'g']
];

var rst = _.unzip(MultArrary);

//[['a','c','f'],['b','d','g']]
console.log(rst);
```

```html
<script data-require="underscore.js@1.8.3" data-semver="1.8.3" src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/underscore.js/1.8.3/underscore-min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use a single approach and build the result in one task.

Your wanted result is in `pivot[0]` and `pivot[1]`.

```js
var multArrary = [['a', 'b'], ['c', 'd'], ['f', 'g']],
    pivot = multArrary.reduce(function (r, a) {
        a.forEach(function (b, i) {
            r[i] = r[i] || [];
            r[i].push(b);
        });
        return r;
    }, []);

console.log(pivot);
```